# Reversing words in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, sorting

does anybody know how can I sort words in string using javascript, jquery.

For example I have this:

```
var words = "1 3 2"
```

Now I want to reverse it to this:

```
var words = "2 3 1"
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sorting, or reversing? Not enough values to tell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are reversing (I'm sure this'll still help if you're not).

```
var original = '1 3 2';
var reversed = original.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
```

Comment: If you had the string "132" this solution would not work because there would not be spaces to split on. However if all you are doing is sorting numbers in the format in your question, yes this solution is simpler.

Comment: @ChrisTek: In that case, you could do `string.split("").reverse().join("");`.  You could do that anyway, even for the example string given.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the basic idea, no need to import jQuery:

```
var words = "1 3 2"

var i=words.length;
i=i-1;

var reversedwords=""; 
for (var x = i; x >=0; x--)
{
    reversedwords +=(words.charAt(x));
}

alert(reversedwords) // "2 3 1"
```

This would also work in reversing the string "string" to "gnirts"

Comment: im sorry, this is cool, but in my case i need reversing of string

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursion. Basically here we are making the function call itself string.length until it hits our base case: an empty string. Every time we chop the first character of the string off using substr() method, and then add it to the end of the string.

```
 var strNum = "1 3 2";
    function reverse(x) {
        if (x == "") {   
        return x;
      }
        return reverse( x.substr(1) ) + x[0];
   };



 reverse(strNum) ==> "2 3 1"
```