# Reversing words in a string JS without using built in function

Tags: javascript, join, reverse, split

Without using the split reverse and join functions, how would one do such a thing?

The Problem Given: Reverse the words in a string 
Sample Input: "Hello World"
Sample Output: "World Hello"

```
<script>
  var newString = ""; 
  var theString = prompt("Enter a Phrase that you would like to reverse (Ex. Hello world)"); 

  newString = theString.split(" ").reverse().join(" ")


  document.write(newString);
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279344/reversing-words-in-a-string)  Not a duplicate based on comments.  ***Restricted from using these methods.  Here's some nails.  Go find a screwdriver to put them in...***

Comment: So you need to avoid using `split` and `reverse`?

Comment: @Ben Aston Yes, its one of the constraints

Comment: You can use split + for loop + if statement. split reverse would be much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays can be used like stacks out of the box. And stacks are LIFO, which is what you need.

```
function reverseWords(str) {
    var word, words, reverse;

    words = str.match(/(?:\w+)/g);
    reverse = '';
    while(word = words.pop()) {
      reverse += word + ' ';
    }

    return reverse.trim();
}

reverseWords('hello world');
```

Or use the call stack as your stack:

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  var result = '';
  (function readWord(i = 0) {
    var word = '';
    if(i > str.length) {
        return '';
    }    
    while(str[i] !== ' ' && i < str.length) {
      word += str[i];
      i++;
    }    
    readWord(++i); // Skip over delimiter.
    result += word + ' ';    
  }());
  return result.trim();
}

reverseWords('hello world');
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the millions of different solutions, the least amount of typing I could come up with involves using `lastIndexOf` and `substring`.

```
var str = "The quick brown fox",
    reversed = "",
    idx;

while(true) {
    idx = str.lastIndexOf(" ")
    reversed = reversed + str.substring(idx).trim() + " "
    if (idx < 0) break;
    str = str.substring(0, idx)
}
reversed.trim()  # Oh, yes, trim too
```

Output:

```
"fox  brown  quick The"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go fancy and try something like this:

I couldn't come up with a shorter solution.

```js
  var newString = "";
  var theString = prompt("Enter a Phrase that you would like to reverse (Ex. Hello world)");

  theString.replace(/[^\s]*/g, function (value) {
      newString = value + ' ' + newString;
  });

  document.write(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for reversing the words in a String is using a Stack data structure. Like so:

```
var newString = "";
var theString = prompt("Enter a Phrase that you would like to reverse (Ex. Hello world)");

var word = "";
var c;
var stack = [];
for (var i = 0, len = theString.length; i < len; i++) {
  c = theString[i];
  word += c;

  if (c == " " || i == (len-1)) {
      word = word.trim();
      stack.push(word);
      word = "";
  }  
}

while (s = stack.pop()) {    
    newString += s + " ";
}

console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do in javascript. Here replace() have /,/g it will replace all comma from the string to space.

```
    var msg = 'Hello world I am Programmer';
    var newstr = msg.split(" ").reverse().join().replace(/,/g, ' ');
    console.log(newstr)
```

;