# I want to reverse a string in javascript without using inbuilt functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

### Input

var str = "ABC PQR XYZ";

### Output

var output = "ZYX RQP CBA";

Comment: AKA you want US to do your homework assignment for you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use "inbuilt functions" for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877226/reversing-words-in-a-string-js-without-using-built-in-function'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's been answered before
[How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

```
function reverse(s) {
var o = '';
for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  o += s[i];
return o;
}
```

Comment: I am getting my desired output. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce for that :

```
'ABC PQR XYZ'.split('').reduce((state, value) => {
    return value + state;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be reversed:

```
 let ouput = "ABC".split``.reverse().join``;
```

Comment: Since you're using ES6, you can use the spread operator to avoid the split:
  [...'ABC PQR XYZ'].reverse().join``

Comment: The instructions were to do it in place without using build in functions, though. But yes, split / reverse / join is the best solution if you're able to use all of the in-built tools.